# How to find regular matrix S,T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Q.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\2&3&-1\end{bmatrix}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ 
For the given A and B, check if there exists a quadratic regular matrix S and a cubic regular matrix T such that $SAT=B$, and if so, find S and T.


I tried to think of all the components of S and T by putting them in letters, but it did not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: From $S A T = B$ , it follows that $ A T = S^{-1} B $.  Let the unknowns be the 9 entries of $T$ and the 4 entries of $S^{-1}$.  Write the 6 equations for the 6 entries of the equation.  Then solve the resulting system by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you very much.